# ajax comment form not posting data to mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I am using ajax to post a comment to a mysql table.  When I post the comment, the javascript is loading but it doesnt submit the data to the mysql database.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#commentform').on('submit',function(e) {
      $.ajax({
         url:'ajax.php',
         data:$(this).serialize(),
         type:'POST',
         success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $("#success").show().fadeOut(5000);
         },
         error:function(data){
            $("#error").show().fadeOut(5000);
         }
      });

      e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

ajax.php

```
$id =   $_POST['id'];
$comment    =   $_POST['comment'];
$username   =   $_POST['username'];

$array = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `comments` (id, comment, user)
VALUES (:id,:comment,:username);");
$array->execute(array(':id' => $id, ':comment' => $comment, ':username' => $username));
```

html

```
<form method="post" name="commentform" id="commentform">
   <textarea name="comment" name="comment"></textarea><br>
   <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo "$id"; ?>" name="id" id="id" />
   <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo "$username"; ?>" name="username" id="username" />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="REPLY" />
</form>
```

Comment: try to debug the code so you may come to know what exact issue you are getting

Comment: Is there an error? Check your networks tab to see why the server side code is failing

Comment: `VALUES (:id,:comment,:username);`<--why is there a semicolon here

Comment: the semicolon is okay there, just do some simple debugging, examine `var_dump($_POST)` on PHP and `console.log(response)` on the success block of ajax. dont forget to turn on error reporting

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the JavaScript console. Does it report any errors? Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect?

Comment: `value="<?php echo "$username"; ?>" ...` in your html form should be `value="<?php echo $username; ?>"` you are litterly echo'ing the word $username in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have issue in html form, you have used multiple `"` around php variables which causes to break the `value` attribute, use updated html

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" name="commentform" id="commentform">
   <textarea name="comment" name="comment">test comment</textarea><br>
   <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" name="id" id="id" />
   <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" name="username" id="username" />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="REPLY" />
</form>
```

Ajax script is fine

here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0mpu2a5y/) which is making ajax request fine

**ajax.php** looks fine as well

```
$id =   $_POST['id'];
$comment    =   $_POST['comment'];
$username   =   $_POST['username'];

$array = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `comments` 
            (id, comment, user) 
                VALUES 
            (:id, :comment, :username)"
         );

$array->execute(array(
            ':id' => $id, 
            ':comment' => $comment, 
            ':username' => $username));
```